# Accessing QMetaObject of the deriving class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a `BaseClass` which is inheriting [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html). It should check invokable methods of the classes which are derived from it for a purpose. I want to know if I can have access to [QMetaObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) of the derived class at some point. Here is a minimal example

```
// class definition of base

class BaseClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit BaseClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE int doSomething(const QString& input1);
};

// class definition of the derived class
class UserClass : public BaseClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UserClass(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE int doSomethingElse(const QString& input1);

};
```

and implementations as follow:

```
BaseClass::BaseClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    auto count = this->metaObject()->methodCount();
    auto offset = this->metaObject()->methodOffset();

    for(int i = offset ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        auto method = this->metaObject()->method(i);
        qDebug() << method.name() <<method.parameterNames();
    }
}

int BaseClass::doSomething(const QString &input1)
{
    return input1.toInt();
}

UserClass::UserClass(QObject *parent): BaseClass(parent)
{
}

int UserClass::doSomethingElse(const QString &input1)
{
    return input1.length();
}
```

When I instantiate the `UserClass`, the output is `"doSomething" ("input1")` and it's quite normal. The `BaseClass` just prints out its own QMetaMethod information.
**My desired output** should include `"doSomethingElse" ("input1")` as well.
Does anyone know some methods to achieve it?

Note: I want to access such information because I want to check the derived class to filter some of its methods by a rule.

**Edit 1:**
I know that the Qt's *meta object compiler* is creating those implementations at compile time and the `BaseClass` should not know anything about the classes that are deriving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work in some way but other methods are also welcomed.
It's not possible to do it directly in the constructor of the `BaseClass` as the deriving class is not instantiated at that point.
So, here is my implementation:

```
BaseClass::BaseClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0,this,[this](){this->check();});
}

void BaseClass::check()
{
    auto count = this->metaObject()->methodCount();
    auto offset = this->metaObject()->methodOffset();

    for(int i = offset ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        auto method = this->metaObject()->method(i);
        qDebug() << method.name() <<method.parameterNames();
    }
}
```

This would print `"doSomethingElse" ("input1")` when I try to create `UserClass` instance.